# bootstrap fails with Windows Azure: XML Schema validation error in network configuration

Tags: juju, cloud

I am trying to test Juju with Windows Azure. I always get this error:

```
PUT request failed: BadRequest - XML Schema validation error in network configuration
```

I have tried several times, with and without `--update-tools` parameter, always the same issue.

The admin certificate is uploaded correctly. The `juju-azure-private` is create inside the windows azure storage and it has new files uploaded.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this error in the past, but not for a while now. The Azure provider has seen various fixes recently, and I'm pretty sure this particular one is no longer an issue. See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1304778